# How to combine (chain) lists recursively?

Tags: python, algorithm, python-3.x, recursion, permutation

For some reason I'm having real trouble wrapping my head around recursive algorithms ...

I was wondering if someone could help me come up with a recursive version of the following:

I have a list of lists of numbers and I want to get all possible lists of permutations of all the elements.

For example, given `[[1], [2,3], [4,5]]`, I want the output to be:

`[[1,2,3,4,5], [1,2,3,5,4], [1,3,2,4,5], [1,3,2,5,4]]`

The way I did it is kind ugly:

```
l = (my list)
perms = [list(permutations(i)) for i in l]
p = perms[0]
for i in range(1, len(perms)):
    p = list(map(lambda x: list(chain.from_iterable(x)), list(product(p, perms[i]))))
    i += 1
print(p)
```

I don't like it ... I feel like recursion might be more elegant.
Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You code can be simplified without recursion:

```
>>> from itertools import chain, product, permutations
>>> l = [[1], [2,3], [4,5]]
>>> perms = [list(permutations(x)) for x in l]
>>> [list(chain.from_iterable(xs)) for xs in product(*perms)]
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [1, 2, 3, 5, 4], [1, 3, 2, 4, 5], [1, 3, 2, 5, 4]]
```

For `product(*perms)`, see [Unpacking Argument Lists - Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists).

Answer (score 3):

You can simplify things a bunch. Just pass all the permutation iterators to `itertools.product` and flatten the lists of lists you get out:

```
my_list = [[1], [2,3], [4,5]]
perms = [permutations(x) for x in my_list]
result = [list(chain.from_iterable(product)) for product in product(*perms)]
```